# Change windows phone 7 silverlight project namespace causes start fail

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I try to change refactor and change default namespace:

Hightlight namespace in MainPage.xaml.cs -> Right click -> Refactor -> Rename
Enter new namespace name and apply for all finded. That change Default namespace in project preferences too.

But after that my project doesn't starts.

How do I change my namespace correctly?

Comment: What is the error? Is it "Could not find schema"?

Comment: You have a few things to change in app.xaml and in the manifest file.

Comment: There is no output just closes immediately. App.xaml changes due refactor automatically... manifest contain only things like title name and etc... doesn't help.

Comment: Duplicate question, I had the same one! Got answered swiftly. @Paul_Diston is correct. See duplicate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103883/wp7-app-crashes-immediately-upon-deploy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the Startup Object, as detailed in the following blog post :-

http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2010/08/04/Windows-Phone-7-Beta-My-Application-Wone28099t-Start-After-Renaming-Project.aspx